# OCR library for photos, not scanned images

Tags: ocr

Does anyone know of an OCR library that can handle colored photos (as opposed to scanned pages)?

It seems to me that most libraries out there work on B&W images and expect them to come from a scanner. I need something that can take a colored photo of, say, a billboard, and extract text from it.

I'm currently considering converting these images to B&W tiffs and feeding them to one of the libraries mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085/free-ocr-library), but I'm skeptical... These library are probably designed around the assumption that images are of scanned documents, or scanned book pages. I need something that would work on text in any orientation, varying sizes, weird alignments, etc. basically something that can extract the most text out of these images - it doesn't have to be 100% accurate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look into a HAL 9000 - Good product though with a few caveats. ;-)

Comment: lol I actually googled it before getting the reference :)

Comment: @Paul Sasik: unfortunately, it has a very little installed base.  also remember the one unit with those caveats is slated for retrieval this year.  (and EOL'd after a bad case of sunburn)

Comment: glad you got a kick out of it! Seriously though, you have some steep requirements for your OCRing. Even the best OCR applications can barely handle plain, black text on a clean, white background and are never 100% accurate. And for the silver lining: You may have qualified for a Tumbleweed badge!

Comment: @Paul, well it wouldn't be my first..

this is a sad state of affairs. The last time I dabbled in OCR was in 1999 and it does not seem to have advanced that much. Converting stuff to B&W tiff is just so depressing to me. All of that information lost, unused. OCR systems seem to have got plenty of non-OCR features added to them but in terms of actual OCR capabilities I don't see anything amazing that was done in the last decade.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpaper for alignment. gocr for OCR. Usually software that gets colour input will convert it to grey scale before processing - it is just a pre-processing step which humans do or the software does itself.

Comment: If humans always converted to gray scale before recognizing character patterns then no one would ever pass a color-blindness test.. :)